# modalViewController not dealocs with ARC

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, memory-management

My view controller I represent modally never get reallocates it is always living (saw by count in instruments).

I saw similar questions on this site, the answers were "you should find what strong object is pointing to the modal view controller"

I cannot find it out, please help me 
here is my code:

here I call for modal view:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self dismissKeyboard];
    [self CheckAndStore:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"At Select");
    self->DetailsView = [[InfoViewController alloc]initWithParameter:[PersonsFromSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    DetailsView.delegate = self;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self presentViewController:DetailsView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

here inside modal view:

```
-(void) Back
{
     NSLog(@"Back Clicked");
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

initWithParameter:

```
- (id) initWithParameter:(id)parameter
{
    Dict = parameter;
    return self;
}
```

inside detailsView.h

```
     @interface InfoViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource , UISearchBarDelegate
,MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
    {
        id<InfoViewControllerDelegate> __weak delegate;
        NSDictionary *Dict;
        …
    }
    @property (weak, nonatomic) id <InfoViewControllerDelegate> delegate; 
    ...
```

DetailsView is an iVar (could it be a problem ?)

If need more code please tell me I will post (I am quite newbie in iOS development).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your `delegate` in `DetailsView` to be `weak` to avoid strong reference cycle. Also you **need** to set your `self->DetailsView` to nil when you want to release it. Because if you still hold a strong reference to it, how could it be deallocated?

Comment: I updated the question with definition of that delegate, it is weak (I guess).

Comment: can I do this inside the back function ?
(since I dont know in parental view when it is about to get dismissed)?

Comment: @Roma-MT If in your presenting view controller you just use `self->DetailsView`, you don't need to declare it to hold a strong reference. Then it will be deallocated when you dismiss. If you need it for other use, you could use delegate method to notify your presenting view controller to tell it that dismiss me!